# After updating to Big Sur the process "opendirectoryd" is using 70% cpu

Tags: big-sur

I've just updated my Macbook Air to Big Sur.

After the update the process `opendirectoryd` is constantly using about 70% of cpu.

I've searched for the same problem, I haven't found any Big Sur related problems. There were recomendations to disable LDAP and/or Active Directory, but I'm not using any.

[image]

After killing the process it appears again. I've searched /var/log/*.log, but I haven't found any errors that can help fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that I have found a way to fix it.

I've edited `/etc/auto_master`, commented out the line starting with `/home`  and then executed `sudo automount -vc`.

I've found this solution here: https://superuser.com/a/426719/117432.

Comment: This worked for in Catalina. Thanks!